# React running debugger out of the blue?

Tags: reactjs

My React app has started running this line out of the blue and interrupting my development. The file is `React_devtools_backend.js`

```
debugger;t.apply(void 0,o)};n.__REACT_DEVTOOLS_ORIGINAL_METHOD__=t,// $FlowFixMe property error|warn is not writable.
```

Any ideas why and how to fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is a bug in React Dev Tools (version: 4.8.0). You can see the issue [here](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/19308). If you use Firefox and update the extension, probably it is going to be fixed. If you are using Chrome, the update is still pending but you can find a temporary solution in the issue link.

[Temporary solution](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/19308#issuecomment-656669792):

> You should also be able to go to Components tab, press Settings gear,
> add checkbox to Break on Warning, then do this again, and remove the
> checkbox as a temporary workaround.

Answer (score 5):

This [issue](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/19308) has a momentarily quick fix if you're on Chrome (react-devtools@4.8.0):

[image: unexpected debugger in devtools 4.8.0]

> - Open React-DevTools > Components.
> - In the upper right corner, click the *Settings* gear icon.
> - Go to the *Debugging* tab.
> - **Check** *Break on Warnings*.
> - **Uncheck** *Break on Warnings*.
> - Finally, reload the page.